# getting input from a user to fill a list in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, input

Ok guys, im just starting C# and trying to transition from the basic side of C++.
I'm working on a lesson(not for a grade, it is a learning assignment), and I have everything set up except for getting the user input. I am trying to use a list instead of an array but I can't figure out how to get it to let the user enter the prices.

This is a project for a simple register. The user has to enter the price. And here will be less than 100 items.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
 static void Main()
 { 
      double i;

      Console.Writeline("Enter Item Prices\n");
      List<double> items = new List<double>[i];
      Console.ReadLine(items);
      Console.WriteLine("{0}: ", i, items[i]);
      for (double i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      {
           items.Add(i);
      }
      return 0;
  }
```

I have all the calcs set up, just can't get the input needed for the prices. I know some things with `i` are wrong. Also, its the `WriteLine` and `ReadLine` taking the place of `cout` and `cin` that is messing me up I think.

I just need to figure out how to get the prices and get them put into my formulas.

I will give the best answer props for helping in my program comments.

**Edit:**

I need it to go back and check if the user want to continue or not

Comment: And you don't want to use a GUI? would be nicer and you'd learn more ;)

Comment: ummm, not really, I just need to print a receipt, but I'll just read it out to the command window instead of actually sending it to a print machine, I think we will get to GUI's after a while, which I can excel in thanks to photoshop, flash, and illastrator

Comment: also, do I still need to format the final price outputs using the "cout.setf(ios::fixed); cout.setf(ios::showpoint); cout.precision(2);" way of doing it in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order is a bit messed up.  Fixed it for you:

```
  Console.Writeline("Enter Item Prices\n");
  List<double> items = new List<double>();
  for (double i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
       string userInput;
       double newItem;

       // repeatedly ask for input from the user until it's a valid double
       do 
       {
           Console.Write(string.Format("Enter item #{0}: ", i));
           // read from console into userInput
           userInput = Console.ReadLine();
       } while (!double.TryParse(userInput, out newItem))

       // add the new item to the array
       items.Add(newItem);
  }

  // output all the items to the console, separated by commas
  Console.WriteLine(
      string.Join(", ", 
          items.Select(item => item.ToString())
      )
  );
```

Comment: ok thanks, so basically I will just need to call userInput into my other functions to go with the calcs?

Comment: and to let it read down just add a "\n" onto the string.join(",")

Comment: @superSport well, you'd want to send `newItem` and `items`.  `userInput` is the raw (string) input.

Comment: @superSport and yes, just replace the comma with "\n" (or Environment.NewLine) in `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: @dbaseman I can't figure out how to exit the loop so the user can finish adding items. I need it to ask he user if they are finished. I have it set up in a switch statement but I can't get it to successfully exit the loop.

Comment: @superSport "break" exits the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal example.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //reading the input and assign it to s
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        //writing the input
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: so like in the other one, just declare "string s" for the overall program and call it in my calc functions right?

Comment: Yeah declare it so that it has the right scope. If you need it everywhere set it for example in your main.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple items (from user input) separated by space into a list as follows:

```
string[] arrItems = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
List<double> lstItems = new List<double>(Array.ConvertAll(arrItems, arrTemp =>
Convert.ToDouble(arrTemp)));
```